# Query problems from Tomcat servlets to MSSQL Server Express 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, servlets

Here's my setup. Running a MSSQL Server Express 2012 in a virtual machine (Fusion). The virtual machine runs on OS X Lion Server. On the OS X Lion a Tomcat 7 server is running. I try the following code from stand alone java:

```
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final static String host = "ip-address:1433";
private final static String database = "databasename";
private final static String user = "user";
private final static String passwd = "password";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+host+";database="+database+";integratedSecurity=true;";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,user,passwd);
        PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from sektor");
        ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
        while(res.next())
            System.out.println("Sektor: " +res.getString("sektornavn"));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This works great and prints the content of the table as hoped for. Now using the same code (only changing output to response from system.out)

```
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final static String host = "ip-address:1433";
private final static String database = "databasename";
private final static String user = "user";
private final static String passwd = "password";


@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    // Write response
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    try {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+host+";database="+database+";";
        writer.println("Connecting<br/>");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,user,passwd);
        writer.println("Preparing statement<br/>");
        PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from sektor");
        writer.println("Executing statement<br/>");
        ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
        while(res.next())
            writer.println("Sektor: " +res.getString("sektornavn")+"<br/>");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writer.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}
```

The problem I have is that in the servlet halts when getting to pstm.executeQuery(). I have narrowed it down to this point by taking out (commentting out) parts of the code and that shows me that it will create a connection (DriverManager.getConnection..) and will prepare statement. Only when adding the pstm.executeQuery() the servlet doesn't respond.

I use the JDBC connector from Microsoft and the jar is available for both the stand alone java and in the servlet. I'm not getting any exceptions to help find the error.

What really puzzels me is that it will get a connection but just not execute the query. All suggestions are much welcomed.

Comment: No idea if it will help or not but have you considered using the jtds jdbc driver? I think it works a lot better than the MS jdbc driver. http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Is any of your text written out at all? A good idea would be to use log4j that way you can write everything that is going on to a log file to help find the cause of the problem.http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

Comment: Thank you for the comments ChadNC. I will try the JTDS driver. I'm using log4j, but removed it from the code for simplicity, but thank you for the advice

Comment: @ChadNC: Thank you very much for pointing me to the JTDS driver. For some reason that worked. I can't tell you why. If you formulate it as an answer, I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I posted that as an answer like you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea if it will help or not but have you considered using the [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) jdbc driver? I have been using he jtds driver for a while now and I have found it to be less problematic than the MS jdbc driver. I used to have wierd things happen that I couldn't explain using the MS driver.